# How to assign strings in a list to another string as a 'shortcut'?

Tags: python

Clarification: The user needs to specify an ID from a displayed list of ID's, how can I simplify the process by numbering the ID's so that the user just has to specify a simple number instead of the whole ID

I have a list `ID = ['ekjgnrg','lrkjnk','etc..']` that I need to interact with by inputting the ID later on. The issue is it's a little tedious to type it in. (Copy-pasting would solve this but it doesn't work on mobile due to the way the message with the list is displayed.)

How can I assign a number to each string in the list so that the user can enter '1' instead of 'ekjgnrg' for simplicity? The list gets longer and shorter occasionally, so how can I make it scale to the size of the list?

Comment: Use a `dict`? `d = {'1': 'ekjgnrg', '2': lrknk', ...}`

Comment: you know that you can get the Nth item of a list with `my_list[N]`? So `my_list[0]` returns the first value (since lists start at zero) and `my_list[1]` returns the second value etc.

Comment: how can i make it scale according to the size of the list? the list gets added and removed automatically by another process, by manually assigning the number it could lead to a situation where it sends 1 = ekjgnrg and 2 = None and takes up space... or am I understanding this wrong? @chepner

Comment: @chepner, we can also store it in the list that way mapping user input with the index of the element? 
For sure, if there are modifications in the list, indices will change so the dictionary will be good for that. But we can always display the list and ask users for their choice?

Comment: @Damiaan it prints the whole list in 1 message, how can I make another list that's "linked" to the first list instead of calling each list item once, with the Nth way of retrieving, it only calls 1 of the strings at a time - right?

Comment: It's really unclear what problem you're trying to solve here. You talk about inputting the whole ID list later on, but then you talk about just assigning a number to a particular string.

Comment: Are you just asking the user to select something from a menu/list?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, to choose something from the list, and trying to facilitate it by inputting a shorter set of characters instead of the full string value.

Comment: @HappyLama OK, please [edit] the question to clarify that. BTW, if you want more tips, see [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you present to user, but, you can do something like:

```
ID = ['ekjgnrg', 'lrkjnk', 'etc..']
print('Choose one of:')
for n,item in enumerate(ID):
    print(f'{n}: {item}')
n = int(input('Enter ID number: '))
print(f'You choose number "{n}" which is "{ID[n]}".')
```

This really needs error checking, like gracefully handling if someone enters invalid data like "foo" or "1000"...

Results in:

```
Choose one of:
0: ekjgnrg
1: lrkjnk
2: etc..
Enter ID number: 1
You choose number "1" which is "lrkjnk".
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Nth item using `my_list[n]` (in your case `my_list` is `ID`).
I suggest you to read: [Python - Access List Items - W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_access.asp) to understand how to work with list or other data structure in Python.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you mean? if not, please elaborate more.

```
ID = ['ekjgnrg','lrkjnk','etc..']
print(ID)
needed_id = int(input("What item do you want from the above list?"))
needed_id -= 1 # since lists start at 0.
print(ID[needed_id])
```

when run:

```
['ekjgnrg', 'lrkjnk', 'etc..']
What item do you want from the above list?1
ekjgnrg
```